# Android menu item. Choosing the position of the icon and the text

Tags: android, icons, title, menuitem

I have a menu with items that contain an icon and text. I want to put the text first and the icon to the right of the text. The icon appears at the left always. Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/txt_cobro"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText">
</item>
```